# geodjango application in rhel 6

Tags: postgis, geodjango, rhel6

I have developed  a geodjango application using python 2.7, django 1.4, mapnik, tilecache and postgis enabled postgresql in ubuntu 12.04.  After completing the development I installed the same application  in RHEL 6, but postgis query using geodjango API is not working.  The query is

the_geom is geometry value from another table

```
placeDet = MyModel.objects.filter(thegeom__dwithin=(the_geom, 250)).distance(the_geom).order_by('distance')
```

and in the Exception it shows the error as,

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Please help me to solve this issue!